# Is Ethereum suitable for permissioned blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum

Got a `blockchain` related project to impl.

Part of the project need permission control, means:

- Only qualified users (*e.g login*) could use it.
- The transaction history is not public, a transaction is only visible to related user or admin user.

It seems `Ethereum` has a lot of features, so trying to re-use it.

**My questions are:**

- Is `Ethereum` also suitable to develop permissioned blockchain?
- If yes, how to impl the permission part.
- If no, then does that means framework like `Hyperledge Fabric` is more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leverage Smart Contracts of Ethereum in Solidity but still be able to use it in a Permissioned Environment, have a look at Hyperledger Burrow (Monax).

https://github.com/hyperledger/burrow

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider Microsoft COCO framework but it is still under development and I think it is targeted to release by end of this year.

"Microsoft's Confidential Consortium Blockchain Framework represents a breakthrough in achieving highly scalable, confidential, permissioned Ethereum or other blockchain networks that will be an important construct in the emerging world of variously interconnected blockchain systems. " - Joseph Lubin, Founder of ConsenSys

Related Blog: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-microsoft-s-coco-framework-for-enterprise-blockchain-networks/